# If I use British English am I wrong?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I went to an American School, and whenever I used Br English, it was wrong.
But say I traveled to Britain with those as my schooling verification? Would I be wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being fluent in a foreign language.

Comment: I know, but english is one language. So why are there two forms?

Comment: 'English is one language' is a misapprehension, an unhelpfully broad-brush notion. Consider 'Cereals are all one type of plant'. _When in Rome, [speak Roman English]_.

Comment: @Coding4el There are many more than two forms of English.

Comment: It is rather puzzling what you mean by 'whenever I used Br English, it was wrong'. I would hope that educated people in the U.S. would be sufficiently familiar with British English not to dismiss it as wrong. (Of course, it wold be a mistake to use **colloquial** British English in a formal educational setting in the U.S., but that would be because of its being colloquial, not because of its being British.)

Comment: @jsw29: I think the "wrong" verdict would have been in elementary school: learning to spell, learning "proper" ways to speak. Other than that, British English should (nowadays) be considered okay in the US.  Maybe another place you would get the "wrong" response would be writing for a publication that enforces a particular style.

Comment: Are you asking whether English-language qualifications from the US would be valid in the UK? Because that's a complex question, and one beyond the scope of this site. I'm not sure what else the question could mean.

Comment: @StuartF That's what I'm asking

Comment: @choster  I didn't know. And why are there so many?

Comment: @GEdgar Ok, so when public, talk in the local english, but when informal, talk with the one I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many aspects of British and American English evolved differently, before the development of international media, because of the geographical separation between the two populations.

Today most British people are used to watching American films etc.  If you come to the UK speaking American English, people will understand you perfectly well (apart from the occasional word which may cause puzzlement or amusement). However, if you were here for some time and needed to do any formal writing, it would be better to learn British spelling and vocabulary.

Comment: Where is "here"? I don't live in the US or the UK and I don't know where you are.

Comment: @CJDennis I thought that saying "If you _come_ to the UK..." made it clear that I was speaking as a British person. Also, the question referred to travelling to Britain.

Comment: Actually, when I first read your answer I thought that due to "however" you were referring to the US. Learning British spelling in the US confused me!

Comment: @CJDennis _However_ means _in spite of this_. The sense was "Even though British people understand the speech of Americans..."

Comment: Do you think I don't speak English? :-) I know what "however" means! What you wrote was akin to a garden path sentence. I thought you were saying one thing and it wasn't until I got to the end of your sentence that I realised you were saying the opposite. I was just trying to point out that saying "here" to refer to a physical location is unclear on the internet.